# Model View Controller with UITextFieldDelegate issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm working with something really easy, and I think I'm making a small mistake that I'm probably just not seeing here. I have this going on between my MVC to simply transfer a name from the `AddViewController` to the `MasterViewController`, and add it to the `MasterController`'s `UITableView`. Although, I have "NSLogged" everything down to each step of the process, and what I'm basically getting out of it is that the text that's inputted into the "name" `UITextField` isn't passing itself into my `NSString` method, `_aname`.

Also, at one point, this was working and I was having trouble with setting the name to the `MasterViewController` from the `AddViewController`. So, if anyone could just give that part a look over too and make sure I have everything set up properly, I would hugely appreciate it.

In a nutshell, it looks like this.

MasterViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AddViewController *addViewController;
```

MasterViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.Name setName:name];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text);

    return cell;
```

Name.h

```
- (NSString *)setName:(NSString *)name;
```

Name.m

```
- (NSString *)setName:(NSString *)name
{
    [_nameStack addObject:name];

    NSLog(@"Name set to: %@", name);

    return name;
}
```

AddViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(finalizeAdditionOfName:)];

    NSUserDefaults *nameDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    nameInput.text = [nameDefault objectForKey:@"Name"];
}

- (IBAction)finalizeAdditionOfName:(id)sender
{
    _name = [[Name alloc] init]
    nameInput.text = _name;
    [_name setName:_aname];
    NSLog(@"Name set to (AddViewController): %@", _aname);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath section] == 0) { // Section 1
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            nameInput.delegate = self;
            [nameInput setEnabled: YES];
            [cell addSubview:nameInput];
            [nameInput becomeFirstResponder]
            nameInput.text = _aname;
            NSUserDefaults *nameDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [nameDefault setObject:_aname forKey:@"Name"];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really work on your naming. Because all of your variables are named "_aname" "nameDefault", etc. it is very hard to read. I'm confused as to what's going on, but I notice that nowhere in your code do you access the `text` property of `UITextField`. In the `finalizeAdditionOfName:` method, presumably you should be accessing the text: `NSString *input = nameInput.text` // Then do something with `input`

Comment: I apologize. They're actually named descriptively, but I felt like I would need to post unnecessary code so I renamed it. I'll give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if my comment doesn't turn out to be helpful, I made a sample project that I think shows how you might get the data from the text field to the table view. Tell me if you have any questions about it:

https://github.com/MaxGabriel/TextField-TableView-Example

Comment: This is a huge help for me. I've been having the hardest time nailing down delegates & protocols. Thank you.