# Passing data into the ViewController using the back button

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have multiple buttons in ViewA. When a button is clicked, it is redirected to ViewB. In ViewB, the user does some interactions, and then clicks the back button when he is done. How do I run a method and pass in a parameter from ViewB into ViewA and then continue working in ViewA?

Using the back button is strongly required, but I am keen to learn if there are other ways.

My idea was to get the ViewA from the stack, and when I am done with ViewB, just call upon it and redirect, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to define a delegate in ViewB and implement it in ViewA.  At the appropriate time (e.g., when the back button is tapped) ViewB call the delegate method, passing the value as a parameter.

Something like this:

ViewB.h

```
// Define a delegate protocol allowing 
@protocol ViewBDelegate

// Method of delegate called when user taps the 'back' button
-(void) backButtonSelected:(id) object;

@end


@interface ViewB : UIViewController

// property to hold a reference to the delegate
@property (weak)id<ViewBDelegate> delegate;

-(IBAction)backButtonSelected:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewB.m:

```
@implementation ViewB

...

-(IBAction)backButtonSelected:(id)sender{
    NSObject *someObjectOrValue = nil;

    // Invoke the delegates backButtonSelected method, 
    // passing the value/object of interest
    [self.delegate backButtonSelected:someObjectOrValue];
}

@end
```

ViewA.h:

```
#import "ViewB.h"


//  The identifier in pointy brackets (e.g., <>) defines the protocol(s)
// ViewA implements
@interface ViewA : UIViewController <ViewBDelegate>

...

-(IBAction)someButtonSelected:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewA.m:

-(IBAction) someButtonSelected:id
    @implementation ViewA

```
...

// Called when user taps some button on ViewA (assumes it is "hooked up" 
// in the storyboard or IB
-(IBAction)someButtonSelected:(id)sender{

    // Create/get reference to ViewB.  May be an alloc/init, getting from storyboard, etc.
    ViewB *viewB = // ViewB initialization code

    // Set `ViewB`'s delegate property to this instance of `ViewA`
    viewB.delegate = self;
    ...
}

// The delegate method (defined in ViewB.h) this class implements
-(void)backButtonSelected:(id)object{
    // Use the object pass as appropriate
}

@end
```

Comment: Using a Protocol and Delegate method is the right way to do this kind of work.

Comment: I made a sample project for a similar question to show how delegation works; might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13285673/1176156

Comment: I'm not really sure how this is suppose to work. Can you give a little more detail? And in ViewA implementation, you have ViewB *viewB = //initialization code. I didn't get that at all.

Comment: @Cartman - Since I don't know how, in your case, `ViewA` transitions to `ViewB`, I put in a vague (and incomplete) piece of code.  The important part is after you have the reference to `ViewB`, you set `ViewB`'s delegate property to your instance of `ViewA` (i.e., `self`).  I'll insert comments in the code above to try to make it more clear.

Comment: In the `backButtonSelected:` method I'd recommend the following conditional check: `if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(backButtonSelected:)])` and make sure that that's true before calling that method on the delegate. ---- UPDATE: I just edited the answer to include this.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS6 you can now use Unwind Segues. In Storyboard you might have noticed the new Exit buttons that can be used for this.

Unwind Segues will allow you to transition back from viewControllerB to viewControllerA and to provide info back through the prepareForSegue method.

Currently documentation is rather limited, but there is a useful WWDC2012 video on how to do this (Session 236)

Comment: Then I guess the delegate approach is your best friend. The actually mention it in the video as the 'old way of working'.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to implement protocol then other way is, you can create property in ViewB of type id like this

> @property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id* parentView;

And set it to ViewA when pushing ViewB like this

> ViewB.parentView = ViewA;
>       //push  ViewB

Then you can call ViewA's methods directly using this property.

Comment: This is not the right direction.  Implementing a Protocol and using the delegate is the right way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: I know implementing a protocol and using the delegate is right way that's why I written "If you don't want to implement protocol....".
@Cartman: You should implement as suggested by bobnoble.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a protocol in ViewControllerA, example name ViewControllerADelegate, create a property delegate in ViewControllerB and in ViewControllerB implement the protocol defined in ViewControllerA.

When you are working in viewControllerB you can notify all your changes to viewControllerA calling methods defined in ViewControllerADelegate, when you will leave viewControllerB you will have viewControllerA updated.

Answer (score 0):

If your ViewA is creating ViewB, you can create a protocol on your ViewB.h and set ViewA as ViewB's delegate. So whenever you change something in ViewB, you can notify ViewA directly.

Depending on your model, you can have a class that holds whichever settings you modify in ViewB. When you create ViewB, you pass the reference normally, and since it's an object, the instance will be shared, so when you go back to ViewA, all the changes are already applied.

```
viewB.settings = self.settings; // or whatever model object you have
```

Another option is to create a custom back button (you will lose the pointy look), have it call your custom method that notifies your ViewA and then does a [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];